# Store an integer in an array where the elements represent 1 byte of the value

Tags: arrays, aes, nesc

I'm using AES to encrypt some data that I'm going to send in a packet.  I need to store an integer in an array of 8 bit elements.  To make this clear, my array is declared as:

```c
uint8_t in[16] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
                  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
```

I need to be able to store an integer in this array and then easily retrieve the data in the receiving client. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are missing language tag... Probably C OR C++

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved via bit-shifting:

```c
int i = 42;
in[0] = i & 0xff;
in[1] = (i >> 8)  & 0xff;
in[2] = (i >> 16) & 0xff;
in[3] = (i >> 24) & 0xff;
```

Note that you cannot always be guaranteed that an int is four bytes. However, it's easy enough to turn the above code into a loop, based on `sizeof i`.

Retrieving the integer works as follows:

```c
int i = in[0] | (in[1] << 8) | (in[2] << 16) | (in[3] << 24);
```

Of course, if you are about to encrypt this with AES, you need to give some thought to a sensible [padding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29). Currently you look like you're heading towards zero-padding, which is far from optimal.